# Как достать сообщение в переменную vk_api Python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Есть код (сам код роли не играет). И нужно например сделать команду: "отправь мне слово, которое я отправлю тебе". Бот отвечает на это сообщение: "Хорошо, слушаю."

Нужно сделать так чтобы бот занёс сообщение в переменную, а потом её выслал мне-же, но БЕЗ цикла while!!!

Если кто не понял, то смысл задачи в том, чтобы заставить бота ждать, чтобы получить сообщение, которое он ждёт. Просто я пишу уже давно бота для вк и только сейчас понял, что т.к мой бот ждёт сообщение после сообщения) "пополнить баланс" после этого он спрашивает "Введите кол-во рублей", а затем ему нужно получить это кол-во рублей, а это у меня реализовано через while, соответственно, если я ничему ему не буду присылать, пока он ждёт моего ответа, то другие не смогут общаться с ботом т.к у меня он находится в цикле.

Надеюсь, что вы поняли.

Comment: Код всегда играет роль, когда вопрос по коду) Как я понял, у вас вложенный цикл, который сосредоточен только на одном пользователе. Вам нужны стейты для организации веточной системы. Можете использовать для этого vkbottle https://vkbottle.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/high-level/handling/state-dispenser/ Либо попытаться сделать похожее с вк_апи

Comment: Ну код может и играет роль, просто он у меня очень большой и там нужно искать, что где. Считай мне нужна просто конкретная задача: Брать сообщение от того пользователя, которого бот попросил ввести кол-во рублей, а другие, всё равно могли пользоваться ботом. Но всё-равно спасибо

Comment: Просто понимаете, переписывать 600 строчек кода, чтобы всё работало на vkbottle - не очень хорошая затея

Comment: В таком случае, посмотрите реализацию этого в вкботтле и сделайте это в своём коде

Comment: Скажу две вещи: 1) Рано или поздно вы придёте к использованию высокоуровневых библиотек. Просто станет лень изобретать велосипед или сделаете примерно тоже самое, что уже есть в других библиотеках. 2) Для вашего решение требуется использовать несколько потоков. Если есть желание, можете почитать в интернете про многопоточность и асинхронность.